# I want help to modify a script to recognize both Firefox and Firefox (Private Browsing)

Tags: bash, scripts

I have this script that runs via a keyboard shortcut (and toggles the Stylus extension stylesheet on/off<sup>***</sup>). It is specifically for maximized windows so the xdotool values won't change:

```
#!/bin/bash

xgg="$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname)"

if [[ "$xgg" == *" - Mozilla Firefox" ]]
  then
    xdotool mousemove --sync 18 54 click 1 
    sleep 0.2
    xdotool mousemove --sync 134 85 click 1
    sleep 0.2
    xdotool mousemove --sync 1365 85 click 1
    sleep 0.2
    xdotool mousemove --sync 683 384
fi
```

It checks if the window in focus is Firefox because of `*" - Mozilla Firefox"`, which is how titles of Firefox windows end,  and, if it matches, it performs the subsequent xdotool commands.

I now would like the xdotool commands to run even if the window is a Private Browsing instance of Firefox.

If I have both a regular Firefox window and a private browsing window open, `wmctrl -l` shows this:

```
$ wmctrl -l
0x0260000b -1    N/A Desktop — Plasma
0x02600016 -1    N/A Plasma
0x03e00018  0 kububb Newest Questions - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox
0x03e001cd  0 kububb Newest Questions - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox (Private Browsing)
0x05a00006  0    N/A bash: dkb — Konsole
$
```

What regex is required for the script to recognize both `- Mozilla Firefox` and `- Mozilla Firefox (Private Browsing)` at the end of the windows' titles?

<sup>***</sup> I have the icon for Stylus to the left of the address bar. When the icon is clicked once, a dropdown appears.The second  click  (in a specific area of the dropdown) toggles the stylesheet on/off.

Comment: `*`? Or you can also use logical OR.

Comment: @pLumo, no, only maximized. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but Stylus can be toggled via shortcut you can set up in the options ...

Comment: The suggestion by @Kulfy works and would be accepted as if posted as an answer.

Comment: @pLumo but yours works as well! I didn't know about it. And it's independent of window size.

Comment: What do the xdotool commands actually do? Are you just trying to minimize the current window?

Comment: @terdon, I have the icon for Stylus to the left of the address bar. When the icon is clicked once, a dropdown appears. Clicking in a specific area of the dropdown toggles the stylesheet on/off. I'll add this to the question. But plumo's advice to use the built-in toggle provided by Stylus itself is better because it works on windows of any size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use asterisk (`*`) wildcard. `*` can represent any number of characters (including zero, in other words, zero or more characters). Therefore, `if` would look like:

```
if [[ "$xgg" == *" - Mozilla Firefox"* ]]
```

Or since there are only two possibilities for Mozilla Firefox, i.e., `Mozilla Firefox` and `Mozilla Firefox (Private Browsing)`, you can use logical OR in `if`  to be more specific.

```
if [[ "$xgg" = *" - Mozilla Firefox" ]] || [[ "$xgg" = *" - Mozilla Firefox (Private Browsing)" ]]
```

Or as per [DK Bose's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186398/i-want-help-to-modify-a-script-to-recognize-both-firefox-and-firefox-private-br/1186429?noredirect=1#comment1982692_1186429):

```
if [[ "$xgg" == *?(" - Mozilla Firefox"|" - Mozilla Firefox (Private Browsing)") ]]
```

Comment: Taking you hint in a comment, I went with `if [[ "$xgg" == *?(" - Mozilla Firefox"|" - Mozilla Firefox (Private Browsing)") ]]`. That works. Re. your first code, please see my comment to terdon's answer re. the `*` at the end. If the code I posted works for you, you can put it in your answer.

Comment: @DKBose Understood and done.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a glob (nitpick, but `==` takes globs not regular expressions) that allows strings after `Firefox`:

```
#!/bin/bash

xgg="$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname)"
if [[ "$xgg" = *"Mozilla Firefox"* ]]
then
    xdotool mousemove --sync 18 54 click 1 
    sleep 0.2
    xdotool mousemove --sync 134 85 click 1
    sleep 0.2
    xdotool mousemove --sync 1365 85 click 1
    sleep 0.2
    xdotool mousemove --sync 683 384
fi
```

Alternatively, since you're using `[[` anyway, you can use the regex match:

```
#!/bin/bash

xgg="$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname)"
if [[ "$xgg" =~ "Mozilla Firefox" ]]
then
    xdotool mousemove --sync 18 54 click 1 
    sleep 0.2
    xdotool mousemove --sync 134 85 click 1
    sleep 0.2
    xdotool mousemove --sync 1365 85 click 1
    sleep 0.2
    xdotool mousemove --sync 683 384
fi
```

Comment: The code I posted ensures the string is at the end of the window title. This makes the chance, however slim, of the shortcut being mistakenly used on a non-Firefox window slimmer. That's why I didn't go with the terminal `*`.

Comment: @DKBose then go with Kulfy's suggestion of `||`.